# Как создать ограничение уникальности с поддержкой ввода null?

Tags: sql, oracle

Создал таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  name  VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  phone NUMBER,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, name),
  unique (id,phone)
);
```

Идея была в том, что бы нельзя было создавать стрики с одинаковыми парами значений в полях `id` и `phone`.

Но при этом поле phone может содержать `null`. Т.е. хочу разрешить создавать одинаковые пары значений в полях `id` и `phone`, если `phone = null`. Во всех других запрещать.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Можно сделать виртуальную колонку, состоящую из пары колонок `id||phone`. Однако, сам факт того, что в такой таблице могут быть не уникальные `ID`, это повод задуматься об архитектуре

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поставить индекс на основе функции:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uk__unique_unless_null ON my_table
    (CASE WHEN phone IS NOT NULL
        THEN id || ',' || phone
    END);
```

Индекс проверяет уникальность строки вида `id,phone` для всех записей по которым заполнен `phone`. Соответственно, будут разрешены дубликаты по `id` для записей с пустым `phone`.

Предполагается, что `id` не содержит запятых, если это не так нужно будет выбрать другой разделитель.

Пример на SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd2172/1